# How to set the size of a DialogFragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment and I would like to set the size of it to 80% of the whole screen. For that I use the following code:

```
public class DialogFR_LevelEnd_Test extends DialogFragment {


    public DialoagFragmentLevelEndingBinding binding;


    public static DialogFR_LevelEnd_Test newInstance(double co2SavingsScore, double neededCO2SavingScore, int currentLevel) {
        DialogFR_LevelEnd_Test fragment = new DialogFR_LevelEnd_Test();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Attempt 1
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int screenWidth = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.80);
        int screenHeight = (int) (displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.80);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.width = screenWidth;
        params.height = screenHeight;
        getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DialoagFragmentLevelEndingBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        //Attempt 2
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int screenWidth = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.80);
        int screenHeight = (int) (displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.80);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.width = screenWidth;
        params.height = screenHeight;
        getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);


        return binding.getRoot();

    }



    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }


}
```

So I try 2 attempst but none of them works. No matter what number I choose, the size is always the same.

Here is the XML layout file of the DialogFragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_outer_constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.44"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.65"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rim"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.98"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/rigthInnerConstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/right_outer_constraintLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/right_outer_constraintLayout"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/right_outer_constraintLayout"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/right_outer_constraintLayout"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id ="@+id/linearLayoutForButtons"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                >


                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/tbutton_highScore_lastWeek"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/tbutton_selector"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textOff="@string/last_week"
                    android:textOn="@string/last_week"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/line1"
                    android:layout_width="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#bcbcbc" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/tbutton_highScore_lastMonth"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/tbutton_selector"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textOff="@string/last_month"
                    android:textOn="@string/last_month"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/line2"
                    android:layout_width="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:background="#bcbcbc" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/tbutton_highScore_overall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/tbutton_selector"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textOff="@string/overall"
                    android:textOn="@string/overall"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_highScoreStatisticsToBeDisplayed"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLayoutForButtons" />




        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>





    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_LevelFinished"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Level Finished"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_CloseSymbol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinished"


        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinished"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinished"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.512"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_symbol_foreground" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_Checkmark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinished"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinished"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinished"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_check_mark_foreground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="You needed to save x g of CO2 and you got y g"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.02"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_CloseSymbol" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageGas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="You saved 10 kWh of Gas"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewGasSymbol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageGas"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageGas"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageGas"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gas2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_NextLevelSymbol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView_RepeatLevel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.85"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_RepeatSymbol"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_foreground" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_RepeatSymbol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.35"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_HighscoreMessagePositions"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_repeat_symbol_foreground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_RepeatLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/repeat_level"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_RepeatSymbol"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_RepeatSymbol"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_RepeatSymbol" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_NextLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next_level"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_NextLevelSymbol"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_NextLevelSymbol"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_NextLevelSymbol" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_leaf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/leaf" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_TopScores"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Top Scores for this Level"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/right_outer_constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/right_outer_constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/right_outer_constraintLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_HighscoreMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="You made it to the Top Score list"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageCO2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_LevelFinishedMessageGas" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_HighscoreMessagePositions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1st this week, 3rd this month, 6th overall"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_HighscoreMessage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_HighscoreMessage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_HighscoreMessage" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Do you know how to do this? Either in the XML layout file or in the Java file?

Update: Here is my themes.xml file

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Game" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>




    <style name="SCBSwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#cd0000</item>

        <!-- inactive thumb color -->
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#327bff
        </item>

        <!-- inactive track color (30% transparency) -->
        <item name="android:colorForeground">#327bff
        </item>


    </style>

    <style name="SwitchStyle">
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#cd0000</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#327bff</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/black </item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomAlertDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="windowFixedWidthMajor">20%</item><!--for landscape-->
        <item name="windowFixedWidthMinor">20%</item><!--for portrait-->
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/CustomAlertDialogTheme</item>
    </style>

    

</resources>
```

**Update**: I tried the solution posted in the answer below but unfortunately, I does not work. Thus, I still have not solved this issue and I would like to know if someone of you has any suggestion as to how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class DialogFR_LevelEnd_Test extends DialogFragment {

    public DialogFragmentLevelEndingBinding binding;

    public static DialogFR_LevelEnd_Test newInstance(double co2SavingsScore, double neededCO2SavingScore, int currentLevel) {
        DialogFR_LevelEnd_Test fragment = new DialogFR_LevelEnd_Test();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DialogFragmentLevelEndingBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }


    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //The following sets the dialog size
        getDialog().setOnShowListener(
                dialog -> {   
                    Point availableDisplaySize = getAvailableDisplaySize(requireActivity());
                    int targetWidth = (int) (availableDisplaySize.x * .8f);
                    int targetHeight = (int) (availableDisplaySize.y * .8f);
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
                    params.width = targetWidth;
                    params.height = targetHeight;
                    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);
                }
        );
    }
}
```

```
public class Util {
    static Point getAvailableDisplaySize(Context context) {
        if (context instanceof Activity && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            WindowMetrics metrics = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getCurrentWindowMetrics();
            WindowInsets windowInsets = metrics.getWindowInsets();
            Insets insets = windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(
                    WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()
                            | WindowInsets.Type.displayCutout()
            );
            int width = metrics.getBounds().width() - insets.right + insets.left;
            int height = metrics.getBounds().height() - insets.top + insets.bottom;
            return new Point(width, height);
        } else {
            Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            return size;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Itp: Thanks a lot Itp for your great help and effort. Your answer works. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of all Dialogs by overriding the `dialogTheme` attribute in your theme with your own ThemeOverlay. That ThemeOverlay can then set `android:windowMinWidthMajor` and `android:windowMinWidthMinor` with the desired width in percentages.

Also, make sure that your Dialog class extends `AppCompatDialogFragment`, not `DialogFragment`. Otherwise, the solution won't work. You can remove the additional code from your Dialog class.

Here is the solution:

```xml
<style name="Theme.Game" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
   ...
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">80%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">80%</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Better to set `windowFixedWidthMinor` and `windowFixedWidthMajor` also. Some % won't work without it.

Comment: You can also add `windowFixedHeightMajor` and `windowFixedHeightMinor` for the height.